# log4j2 web.xml: define location of configuration xml file

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 logger on a web application. I define a listener in the web.xml like that:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I followed the log4j documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

On my Tomcat server I'm running multiples web applications. I need to have different logging configuration by application.
I tried to use this property:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///etc/log4j-appName.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Put it doesn't work (also with file:${env:catalina.base}/etc/log4j-appName.xml)

How can I define a log4j2 xml file by web application (outside the war)?

Part of my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///etc/log4j-appName.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher><!-- Servlet 3.0 w/ disabled auto-initialization only; not supported in 2.5 -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: You should run `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` to find out what are you missing (a detailed log will appear on `stdout`, usually `catalina.out`). Is the config file in `/etc/log4j-appName.xml`? Is it readable by Tomcat?